# TABLEAU: How to create a single calculated field from multiple columns filtering

Tags: tableau-api

I am fairly new to tableau and have searched in various online help forums but was unsuccessful in finding the one similar to mine. Hence posted this here. Not sure if this is a fairly straightforward one or complicated (as I think!)

I have 3 columns (2 dimensions and 1 measure) and I want to use the measure column based on some of the string occurances from the dimensions columns.

Let the columns be as 'Event', 'Screen' and 'Time'

Let the values be as in the following table (NOTE: There are many other values along with these, but I require only the ones in the lower cases i.e., NULLs and NAVIGATIONs are to be excluded)

[image]

I want a **single calculated field** with three steps that yields as below:

(2*count of "name submitted" occurances in **Event**)  - (AVG **time** of corresponding "name submitted" (from **Event**) * count of "name submitted" occurances in **Event**)
                          **+**

(2*count of "address added" occurances in **Event**) - (AVG **time** of corresponding "Add address" (from **screen**) * count of "address added" occurances in **Event**)
**+**

(2*count of "order created" occurances in **Event**) - (AVG **time** of corresponding sum of "orders"+"order detail"+"order confirmation" (from **screen**) * count of "order created" occurances in **Event**)

**My approach:**

I have dragged **Event** and **Screen** dimensions to the **filter pane** and selected all the values including NAVIGATION AND NULL (as these fields correspond to the time that I need in the calculation) and it didn't quite work!

I have also created PARAMETERS for Event and Screen for each of the three steps of the calculation (above) and it didn't work either!

So, what would be a best way to achieve the above calculation?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Note, there are discrepancies in capitalization between the example data and your example calc (Name submitted vs name submitted), so you may need to adjust the below for that.

```
(
    (2 * SUM(IIF([Event] = 'Name submitted',1,NULL)))
    - 
    (
        AVG(IIF([Event] = 'Name submitted',[Time],NULL))
        * SUM(IIF([Event] = 'Name submitted',1,NULL))
    )
)

+

(
    (2 * SUM(IIF([Event] = 'Address added',1,NULL)))
    -
    (
        AVG(IIF([Screen] = 'Add address',[Time],NULL))
        * SUM(IIF([Event] = 'Address added',1,NULL))
    )
)

+

(
    (2 * SUM(IIF([Event] = 'order created',1,NULL)))
    -
    (
        AVG(IIF([Screen] = 'orders'
                OR [Screen] = 'order detail'
                OR [Screen] = 'order confirmation'
            ,[Time],NULL))
        * SUM(IIF([Event] = 'order created',1,NULL))
    )
)
```

Comment: Edited the middle section to avg time using criteria of screen per the requirements/example calculation.

Comment: I have been using IF() instead of IIF(). Would you mind explaining the difference between these two? as it might help me in  understanding the solution more better. Thanks!

Comment: IF isn't a function, it's a statement (so no IF()). Generally the only difference is syntax. Any use of IIF could be re-written as an IF statement and also as a CASE statement. At least I can't think of a scenario where that wouldn't be true. When inside another function (e.g. SUM), I always use IIF because it's shorter and more readable in my opinion. Just my preference.

Answer (score 0):

You can account for filters in calculations. So for your first part, it could be something like the following:

```
(2*count(if [Event]='name submitted' then [number of records] end)) - avg(if [Event]='name submitted' then [time] end)*count(if [Event]='name submitted' then [number of records] end)
```

I'm not sure about your order of operations but you can adjust as needed. Repeat this format for your other calcs.

Comment: What does [number of records] mean in correspondance to my question?

Comment: It is a default measure that appears at the end of your measures list. It is just a calculated field with a "1".